# share arraylsit among request in Spring controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I used the same ArrayList in 2 webservices in spring controller, so I want to get it once from DB using request or session scope I tried to make a bean

```
@WebAppConfiguration
public class exampleBean {
List<user> users = new ArrayList<user>();

@Bean
@Scope(value = "request")
public List<user> getuserList(){
    return users ;
}

@Bean
@Scope(value = "request")
public void setAttendessList(List<user>  userList){
    users = userList;
}
```

}

And in Controller

ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(exampleBean .class);
    AttendeesBean attendeeBean = ctx.getBean(exampleBean .class);

and in first service I set the list, but didn't find it in second service.

Comment: beacuse of set the scope to `request`, don't give it any scope then it will be considered as singleton and will be available throught all the request in your app.

Comment: Also if you don't want this list to be static, then you should make the `scope` as session.

Comment: I tried to change it to session scope and it worked @AmitK Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with the `scope`, when you define `request` scope, value or bean will be available on a single request and won't be available for other requests. Read [spring scopes](http://javabeat.net/spring-bean-scopes-request-session-global-session-example/%20spring%20scopes) for more info.

So Once you changed the scope to `session` then all bean/object created in one request will be available for all other requests in the same session. Hence changing scope to `session` solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed @Scope(value ="request") to 
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)

using @AmtiK advice and with some searching.

And it worked